# Retrieve child records ordered by another parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This associations worked OK in Rails 3, so for a User I could get UserQuest ordered by Quest.status. I can't find how to get this in Rails 4. Thanks for the help.

```
class Quest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_quests
end

class UserQuest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quest
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_quests, :include => :quest, :order => "Quest.status DESC", :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_quests,
           -> { includes(:quest).order('quests.status DESC') },
           :dependent => :delete_all
end
```